# postgresql - view schema privileges

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

Is there a query I can run to show currently assigned privileges on a particular schema?

i.e. privileges that were assigned like so:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA dbo TO MyUser
```

I have tried

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.usage_privileges;
```

but this only returns grants to the built-in PUBLIC role. Instead, I want to see which users have been granted privileges on the various schema.

Note: I'm actually using Amazon Redshift rather than pure PostgreSQL, although I will accept a pure PostgreSQL answer if this is not possible in Amazon Redshift. (Though I suspect it is)

Comment: Check out what `psql` does when you do a `\dp viewname` query, by running `psql` with the `-E` flag. Should get you started. I don't use Redshift, so not pursuing further.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

in console util psql:

```
\dn+
```

will show you

```
     Name      |  Owner   |   Access privileges   |      Description
```

Comment: this only shows me the public db under "list of schemas"

Comment: How does one interpret the Access Privileges column? I see `lemon_service=U/postgres`, but what does `=U/postgres` mean?

Comment: `U` = USAGE (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html#PRIVILEGE-ABBREVS-TABLE), and `/postgres` is a information about who has granted this.

Answer (score 45):

List all schemas with their priveleges for current user:

```
WITH "names"("name") AS (
  SELECT n.nspname AS "name"
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
      WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
        AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
) SELECT "name",
  pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(current_user, "name", 'CREATE') AS "create",
  pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(current_user, "name", 'USAGE') AS "usage"
    FROM "names";
```

The response will be for example:

```
  name   | create | usage 
---------+--------+-------
 public  | t      | t
 test    | t      | t
 awesome | f      | f
(3 rows)
```

In this example current user is not owner of the `awesome` schema.

As you could guess, similar request for particular schema:

```
SELECT
  pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(
    current_user, 'awesome', 'CREATE') AS "create",
  pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(
    current_user, 'awesome', 'USAGE') AS "usage";
```

and response:

```
 create | usage 
--------+-------
 f      | f
```

As you know, it's possible to use `pg_catalog.current_schema()` for current schema.

Of all the possible privileges

```
-- SELECT
-- INSERT
-- UPDATE
-- DELETE
-- TRUNCATE
-- REFERENCES
-- TRIGGER
-- CREATE
-- CONNECT
-- TEMP
-- EXECUTE
-- USAGE
```

the only `CREATE` and `USAGE` allowed for schemas.

Like the `current_schema()` the `current_user` can be replaced with particular role.

---

**BONUS** with `current` column

```
WITH "names"("name") AS (
  SELECT n.nspname AS "name"
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
      WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_'
        AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
) SELECT "name",
  pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(current_user, "name", 'CREATE') AS "create",
  pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(current_user, "name", 'USAGE')  AS "usage",
  "name" = pg_catalog.current_schema() AS "current"
    FROM "names";

--   name   | create | usage | current
-- ---------+--------+-------+---------
--  public  | t      | t     | t
--  test    | t      | t     | f
--  awesome | f      | f     | f
-- (3 rows)
```

---

[WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) | [System Information Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html) | [GRANT (privileges)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html)

Comment: Worked for me, but is the `RECURSIVE` keyword doing anything nontrivial there?  The PostgreSQL docs seem to imply that a truly "recursive" query should have a `UNION` in it.

Comment: @user1071847, sure. `RECURSIVE` is unnecessary here. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 19):

This is what psql uses internally :)

```
SELECT n.nspname AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(n.nspowner) AS "Owner",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(n.nspacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(n.oid, 'pg_namespace') AS "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 17):

The privileges are stored in the nspacl field of pg_namespace.  Since it's an array field, you have to do a little fancy coding to parse it.  This query will give you the grant statements used for users and groups:

```
select 
'grant ' || substring(
          case when charindex('U',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',usage ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('C',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',create ' else '' end 
       , 2,10000)
|| ' on schema '||nspname||' to "'||pu.usename||'";' 
from pg_namespace pn,pg_user pu
 where  array_to_string(nspacl,',') like '%'||pu.usename||'%' --and pu.usename='<username>' 
and nspowner > 1 
union
select 
'grant ' || substring(
          case when charindex('U',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),pg.groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',usage ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('C',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(nspacl, '|'),pg.groname,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',create ' else '' end 
       , 2,10000)
|| ' on schema '||nspname||' to group "'||pg.groname||'";' 
from pg_namespace pn,pg_group pg
 where array_to_string(nspacl,',') like '%'||pg.groname||'%' --and pg.groname='<username>' 
 and nspowner > 1
```

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but I don't seem to have charindex on my 9.4 installation.  Is this some sort of custom function?

Comment: No, it's not a custom function.  Looks like you are referring to Postgres as opposed to Redshift which has it.  In Postgres I believe it was deprecated and the equivalent function is strpos.

Answer (score 8):

For current question can try this one:

```
SELECT r.rolname AS role_name,
       n.nspname AS schema_name,
       p.perm AS privilege
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS n
    CROSS JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles AS r
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('USAGE'), ('CREATE')) AS p(perm)
WHERE has_schema_privilege(r.oid, n.oid, p.perm)
--      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
--      AND n.nspname !~~ 'pg\_%'
--      AND NOT r.rolsuper
```

Could be pretty low in performance at database with a lot of objects and users with which I have come across. So i've got possible workaround using [`aclexplode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54885448) default function like this:

```
SELECT  oid_to_rolname(a.grantee) AS role_name,
        n.nspname AS schema_name,
        a.privilege_type AS privilege_type
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS n,
        aclexplode(nspacl) a
WHERE n.nspacl IS NOT NULL 
        AND oid_to_rolname(a.grantee) IS NOT NULL 
--      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
--      AND n.nspname !~~ 'pg\_%'
```

But, **be careful**, last one doesn't include privileges which users have obtained from `PUBLIC` role.
Where `oid_to_rolname()` is simple custom function `SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE oid = $1`.

And, like [@Jaisus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10696598/jaisus), my task required to have all privileges which all users have. So i have similar to `schema` privileges queries for `table`, `views`, `columns`, `sequences`, `functions`, `database` and even `default` privileges.

Also, there is helpful extension [`pg_permission`](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_permission) where I get logic for provided queries and just upgraded it for my purposes.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one (works for PUBLIC role):

```
SELECT nspname,
       coalesce(nullif(role.name,''), 'PUBLIC') AS name,
       substring(
          CASE WHEN position('U' in split_part(split_part((','||array_to_string(nspacl,',')), ','||role.name||'=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 THEN ', USAGE' ELSE '' END 
          || CASE WHEN position('C' in split_part(split_part((','||array_to_string(nspacl,',')), ','||role.name||'=',2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 THEN ', CREATE' ELSE '' END 
       , 3,10000) AS privileges
FROM pg_namespace pn, (SELECT pg_roles.rolname AS name
   FROM pg_roles UNION ALL SELECT '' AS name) AS role
 WHERE (','||array_to_string(nspacl,',')) LIKE '%,'||role.name||'=%'
 AND nspowner > 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

Even more concisely, one can do:

```
  SELECT 
    n.nspname AS schema_name
   FROM pg_namespace n
  WHERE  has_schema_privilege('my_user',n.nspname, 'CREATE, USAGE');
```

Answer (score 6):

For the last year there was no update on this question. However as I see it there is one more answers to this question.

```
SELECT grantor, grantee, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM information_schema.table_privileges
WHERE grantee = 'userName';
```

This can give a detailed look on the table privileges.

I saw this answer fit for the databases that are not owned by the supposed user. For partial access grant you can use this to verify the access on the schema's tables.

Answer (score 5):

Combined version (groups, users, PUBLIC) that works for AWS Redshift:

```
    SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CASE
               WHEN charindex ('U',SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(ARRAY_TO_STRING(nspacl,'|'),pu.usename,2),'/',1)) > 0 THEN ' USAGE'
               ELSE ''
             END ||case WHEN charindex('C',SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(ARRAY_TO_STRING(nspacl,'|'),pu.usename,2),'/',1)) > 0 THEN ' CREATE' ELSE '' END AS rights,
             nspname AS schema,
             '' AS role,
             pu.usename AS user
      FROM pg_namespace pn,
           pg_user pu
      WHERE ARRAY_TO_STRING(nspacl,',') LIKE '%' ||pu.usename|| '%'
      --and pu.usename='<username>' 
      AND   nspowner > 1

  UNION

      SELECT CASE
               WHEN charindex ('U',SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(ARRAY_TO_STRING(nspacl,'|'),pg.groname,2),'/',1)) > 0 THEN ' USAGE '
               ELSE ''
             END ||case WHEN charindex('C',SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(ARRAY_TO_STRING(nspacl,'|'),pg.groname,2),'/',1)) > 0 THEN ' CREATE' ELSE '' END as rights,
             nspname AS schema,
             pg.groname AS role,
             '' AS user
      FROM pg_namespace pn,
           pg_group pg
      WHERE ARRAY_TO_STRING(nspacl,',') LIKE '%' ||pg.groname|| '%'
      --and pg.groname='<username>' 
      AND   nspowner > 1

  UNION

      SELECT CASE
               WHEN POSITION('U' IN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART((',' ||array_to_string (nspacl,',')),',' ||roles.name|| '=',2),'/',1)) > 0 THEN ' USAGE'
               ELSE ''
             END 
      || CASE
               WHEN POSITION('C' IN SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART((',' ||array_to_string (nspacl,',')),',' ||roles.name|| '=',2),'/',1)) > 0 THEN ' CREATE'
               ELSE ''
             END AS rights,
             nspname AS schema,
             COALESCE(NULLIF(roles.name,''),'PUBLIC') AS role,
             '' AS user
      FROM pg_namespace pn,
           (SELECT pg_group.groname AS name
            FROM pg_group
            UNION ALL
            SELECT '' AS name) AS roles
      WHERE (',' ||array_to_string (nspacl,',')) LIKE '%,' ||roles.name|| '=%'
      AND   nspowner > 1) privs

ORDER BY schema,rights
```

Comment: Do you this query for aws RDS postgres db ?
I am looking for that one from few days. If you have it that would be big help.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old but I made another query based on the different answers to have one that is short and easy to use afterward :

```
select
    nspname as schema_name
    , r.rolname as role_name
    , pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(r.rolname, nspname, 'CREATE') as create_grant
    , pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege(r.rolname, nspname, 'USAGE') as usage_grant
from pg_namespace pn,pg_catalog.pg_roles r
where array_to_string(nspacl,',') like '%'||r.rolname||'%' 
    and nspowner > 1
```

I keep thinking one day I will make a query to have all rights in only one view... One day. ;)

Comment: I just think it is more readable than the previous answer (less string manipulation) and compliant with pure PostgreSQL code. And it is directly 'queriable' if you put it into a view. For example : SELECT * FROM new_view WHERE usage_grant = true;

Comment: In fact I have even shorter, I edit my code right away.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful and more clear than some of the other answers.