# Schema USAGE privilege for DB user

Tags: database, postgresql, schema, sql-grant

Is there a query which tells what all DB schema's does a postgres DB user has access to in a multi schema POSTGRES Database ?

Comment: Already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715053/postgresql-view-schema-privileges.

Comment: Thanks - this was helpful