# How do I resolve a "permission denied for schema public" error for PostgreSQL on GitHub Actions?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, github-actions, postgresql-14

I've been working on maintenance on this GitHub repo that has been left undeveloped for almost a year. When rerunning the GitHub Actions job that finished to completion last May, there are now issues related to permission for `CREATE` in the public schema in PostgreSQL. At first I suspected, this might be because of the recent PostgreSQL 15 update that made it so that users do not by default have create access on the public schema. However, for our job GitHub Actions uses Postgres 14 for Ubuntu 22.04 (postgresql_14+238), so this change to public schema access in PostgreSQL shouldn't be affecting us. Our previous passing run used Postgres 12 for Ubuntu 20.04 (postgresql-12_12.10-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), so the changed environment could still be relevant.

The job is erroring out during a step where we create a few tables within our database using <user>:

```
peewee.ProgrammingError: permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "articles" ("id" INTEGER NOT NULL...
```

Before this step, we configure the PostgreSQL database, creating the <user> and granting it all permissions to the database: `

```
CREATE USER <user>;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <db_name> to <user>
```

To remedy this problem (while still being confused on why it arose), I tried to explicitly grant <user> permissions on the public schema before attempting any `CREATE`s following the suggestions from this post: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/error-permission-denied-schema-public/

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO <name>;
```

which seems to go through based on the returned `GRANT` .

Locally, I'm having no issues with permissions even without the `GRANT` using PostgreSQL 14, but the permission error still comes up on GitHub Actions, even after granting access to the public schema to the user (and in a desperate attempt--to all users).

I've done a bunch of sanity checks related to making sure that we are in fact using the <user> during the `CREATE` step, but it seems like the <user> just never ends up getting the permissions even after the `GRANT`. I followed [postgresql - view schema privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715053/postgresql-view-schema-privileges) to view schema privileges, and locally, the <user> has permissions to the public schema even before the `GRANT`. However, on GitHub Actions, the <user> doesn't have permissions before nor after the `GRANT`, even though there is output confirmation that the `GRANT` completed successfully.

Does anyone know why I would be having these permission errors now on GitHub Actions, despite the code working locally and on GitHub Actions months ago? Is there any way I can grant permissions differently that might work better in this environment?

Answer (score 5):

The permissions on schema `public` changed in v15. This change finally got rid of the insecure default setting of letting every user create objects in that schema. Now only the database owner is allowed to create objects by default.

Your `GRANT` statement is good to allow a user to create objects in schema `public`:

```
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO user_that_creates_objects;
```

Just remember that you have to connect to the target database before running that statement. Also, the `GRANT` must be executed by the database owner or a superuser.

My recommendation is to leave the `public` schema for extension objects and create your own schema for your application objects.