# find out elevated privileges in Postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

I was trying to find out the user/roles which got elevated privileges in the postgres database.
Elevated privileges like alter/drop/create/owner of table i.e. any user who can change the existing tables or can create/drop the table..
I was going through the different views under information_schema an pg_catalog but did not find out the correct table, most of the views showcase Read-write privileges only like select/insert/update/delete.
So, could anyone help here to find out the correct table or redirect to the query which could provide the desired results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DROP/ALTER - The right to drop an object, or to alter its definition in any way, is not treated as a grantable privilege; it is inherent in the owner, and cannot be granted or revoked [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-grant.html#:%7E:text=The%20right%20to%20drop%20an,the%20object%3B%20see%20below.)  .  
CREATE privilege is only on `SCHEMA` and not table. Below query from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715053/postgresql-view-schema-privileges#:%7E:text=Even%20more%20concisely,at%2013%3A39)
gives the schemas where a user has create privilege

```
SELECT 
    n.nspname AS schema_name
   FROM pg_namespace n
  WHERE  has_schema_privilege('user',n.nspname, 'CREATE');
```